# Issue with materialized query result - LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a List that includes IQueryAble inside as a property. I'm passing List to my View in MVC project. I iterate through the List using foreach. Inside the foreach:

Albums in type of List

```
<% foreach(var x in Albums){%>

 <h1><%= x.Title %></h1>
<p><%= x.Photos.Count() %> </p>

<%}%>
```

Displaying the Title is not an issue, but it throws an error as soon it hits the Count(): "This method is not supported against a materialized query result."

what does this mean? I cannot have collection inside a collection? as soon as I iterate through the collection, the other collection inside that class is not useable anymore.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a presentation model:

```
public class AlbumPresentation
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int PhotoCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then [project onto the model](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/) in your controller:

```
var model = (from a in Context.Albums // or, more likely, via a repository
             select new AlbumPresentation
             {
                 Title = a.Title,
                 PhotoCount = a.Photos.Count()
             }).ToList();
return View(model);
```

The type of your View is now `ViewPage<IEnumerable<AlbumPresentation>>`.

Note that unlike using eager loading (`Include()`), you are no longer required to load all of the Photo records from the database just to get the count. You *can* load that information if you need it, but only if you need it.

Comment: I think this would work, but I need to change the underlaying model. I use presentation model. In my presentation model I have this

public class AlbumViewModel{
  public List<Album> MyAlbums {get;set:}
}

inside each of Album there are photos. Looks like I cannot do any Linq extension operation from inside a collection which I'm iterating. Just don't see the reason why.

Comment: You only need to change your model enough to add one `int` property to it (for the count). As for why, I think there's more code you're not showing us here. "Materialized query result?" Your tags say EF, but that sounds like L2S to me.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue myself and googling didn't help.  I figured out the simplest way to fix the code.  Simply add a .ToList() before the .Count() and it will work fine.

```
<% foreach(var x in Albums){%>

 <h1><%= x.Title %></h1>
<p><%= x.Photos.ToList().Count() %> </p>

<%}%>
```

The collection inside the collection hasn't been evaluated yet so you can't get a count for it.  I'm guessing it's trying to save execution time in case you don't use the inner collection.

example:

```
    var result = (from tsk in db.Tasks
                 where tsk.result == "Success"
                 orderby tsk.data_end descending
                 select new
                 {
                     tsk.data_end,
                 //here's an inner collection
                     nodes = (from err in db.Errors
                              where err.QueryEnd == tsk.data_end
                              select err.NodeName).Distinct()
                 }).ToList();
```

result.nodes isn't evaluated yet because there isn't a .toList() on it.  If you try to add this, it will throw an exception.

result.nodes[0].Count() will throw an error.

result.nodes[0].ToList().Count() will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to include Photos in your Albums query.  Something like.

```
var Albums = from a in context.Ablums.Include("Photos") select a;
```

Comment: the collection of foto is already included, if I debug it I can see it in my controller, but once I iterate through the albums and try to count the photos inside the album (inside the iteration), it throw that error.